# Kafka conumer.poll() argument

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

What does the argument in the .poll method mean?

```
ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);
```

Does it mean that consumer will block the execution for 100ms when there is no data in the partition? Or does it mean that it will keep polling for 100ms and batch those data for 100ms and then return?

If I may ask it differently, does the argument hold meaning only in cases of no data in the partition or does it mean that data or no-data the consumer will block for 100ms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The poll call is a blocking call from the kafka consumer. The call will return in one of the two conditions:

1. **poll duration times out**: The kafka cluster will return the consumer with all the *new* messages that have been published to the topic partition (that consumer has subscribed to) and have not been processed by the consumer.
2. **max.poll.records have been reached**: As part of kafka consumer config, max number of records to be read in a poll is configured as well. So if we are polling for 1min with max poll records as 1000, the poll call will return if 1000 new messages are available even if 1min is *NOT* over yet.

Answer (score 0):

**Parameters:**

public ConsumerRecords<K,V> poll(Duration timeout)

timeout - The maximum time to block (must not be greater than Long.MAX_VALUE milliseconds)

And yes, it looks like he is blocking the partition

https://kafka.apache.org/26/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html