# Kafka Consumer - How to set fetch.max.bytes higher than the default 50mb?

Tags: configuration, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I want my consumers to process large batches, so I aim to have the consumer listener "awake", say, on 1800mb of data or every 5min, whichever comes first.

Mine is a kafka-springboot application, the topic has 28 partitions, and this is the configuration I explicitly change:

| Parameter | Value I set | Default Value | Why I set it this way |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| fetch.max.bytes | 1801mb | 50mb | fetch.min.bytes+1mb |
| fetch.min.bytes | 1800mb | 1b | desired batch size |
| fetch.max.wait.ms | 5min | 500ms | desired cadence |
| max.partition.fetch.bytes | 1801mb | 1mb | unbalanced partitions |
| request.timeout.ms | 5min+1sec | 30sec | fetch.max.wait.ms + 1sec |
| max.poll.records | 10000 | 500 | 1500 found too low |
| max.poll.interval.ms | 5min+1sec | 5min | fetch.max.wait.ms + 1sec |

Nevertheless, I produce ~2gb of data to the topic, and I see the consumer-listener (a Batch Listener) is called many times per second -- way more than desired rate.

I logged the serialized-size of the `ConsumerRecords<?,?>` argument, and found that it is never more than 55mb.
This hints that I was not able to set fetch.max.bytes above the default 50mb.

Any idea how I can troubleshoot this?

---

Edit:
I found this question: [Kafka MSK - a configuration of high fetch.max.wait.ms and fetch.min.bytes is behaving unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72812954/kafka-msk-a-configuration-of-high-fetch-max-wait-ms-and-fetch-min-bytes-is-beh?rq=1)

Is it really impossible as stated?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the cause.

There is a **broker** fetch.max.bytes setting, and it defaults to 55mb. I only changed the consumer preferences, unaware of the broker-side limit.

see also
The [kafka KIP](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-541%3A+Create+a+fetch.max.bytes+configuration+for+the+broker) and the [actual commit](https://github.com/apache/kafka/pull/7595/commits).